# Did Sri Madhusudana saraswati leave advaita at the end of life?

Tags: advaita, vaishnavism, adi-shankaracharya, dashanami

There are many stories saying Sri Madhusudana saraswati leave advaita and worshipped Sri Krishna. Some claim that he was bhakta of Shri Krishna from his child hood and just left debate and worshipped Shri Krishna,but to the best of my knowledge he never wrote anything against advaita.Which story is correct? And please share post-life of Sri Madhusudana saraswati.

Comment: Why would worshipping Krshna mean leaving Advaita? Krshna seems to describe himself like/as Brahman in the Bhagavad Gita anyway.

Comment: @Anpakarana Abhibhaa according to gaudiyas Sri Madhusudan Saraswati left advaita and worshipped Sri Krishna so I asked.